# programmatically creating a UITabBarController subViews not loading UITabBarItem images

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I am programicaly loading Storyboards into a UITabBarController but for some reason UITabBarItem are not loading the image or selectedImage for all  except the first Tab are not loading

[image: Appearance when app first loads]

But if you tap other tabs icons load

[image: After tabing through all tabs]

Loading Storyboard Example

```
import UIKit

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let defaultImag = UIImage(named: "Profile")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        let selectedImag = UIImage(named: "Profile_selected")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

        self.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: defaultImag, selectedImage: selectedImag)
        self.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: -10, right: 0);
    }

}
```

UITabBarController

```
import UIKit

class TabBarViewController:  UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)


        let discoverStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Discover", bundle: nil)
        let discoverViewController = discoverStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()! as UIViewController

        let favouritesStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Favourites", bundle: nil)
        let favouritesViewController = favouritesStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()! as! FavouritesViewController

        let profileStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Profile", bundle: nil)
        let profileViewController = profileStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()! as UIViewController

        self.viewControllers = [discoverViewController, favouritesViewController, profileViewController]

    }
}
```

Comment: image is not loading?

Comment: I have added screen shots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private func createTabForStoryBoard(storyBoardName: String, title: String, imageName :String, tag: Int) -> (UINavigationController) {

        let storyboard  = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardName as String, bundle: nil)
        let viewController  = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UIViewController

        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        let tabBarItem:UITabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: NSLocalizedString(title, comment: "Tab Bar Names") , image: image, tag: 0)

        viewController.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
        return viewController

    }


    // MARK: Custom Methods

    func setTabBarViewControllers() {
        let discoverViewController = self.createTabForStoryBoard("Discover", title: "Discover", imageName: "<image-name>", tag: 1)

        let favouritesViewController = self.createTabForStoryBoard("Favourites", title: "Favourites", imageName: "<image-name>", tag: 2)

        let profileViewController = self.createTabForStoryBoard("Profile", title: "Profile", imageName: "<image-name>", tag: 3)

        let tabBarViewControllers = [discoverViewController, favouritesViewController, profileViewController]
        self.viewControllers = tabBarViewControllers
    }
```

Comment: Moving the Init of the UITabBarItem to the custom  UITabBarController worked but why didn't it work if the UIViewController has been init with a UITabBarItem it should read its values when the Tab is loaded no?